# Como tomar los valores de los inputs Arrays en diferentes TABS - PHP (codeigniter) -> JS

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

Tengo un formulario, donde por defecto se crea un TAB:

https://www.codeply.com/p/VLtyJE4POf

El incoveniente que tengo es que cuando creo un nuevo, por ejemplo, TAB2 se crea pero con el mismo valor que el TAB1.

Como puedo solucionar este incoveniente? y como tomo los valores de todos los TABS?

pense en hacer un bucle for como este:

```
//ASIGNAMOS VARIABLES A LOS ARREGLOS DEL TABLE GRUPO FAMILIAR.
      $items1 = ($_POST['nombre']);
      $items2 = ($_POST['apellido']);
      // Recorrer con ciclo for
      for($i = 0; $i < count($items1); $i++) {
        // Usar el mismo índice para acceder a todos los elementos
        $item1 = $items1[$i];
        $item2 = $items2[$i];
        //POR CADA ITERACION CARGA EN LA BASE DE DATOS EL GRUPO FAMILIAR.
        if($item1 != '' && $item2 != '' && $item3 != ''){
          //$this->cargar_archivosgrupofamiliar($item1,$item2);
          $datafamiliar = array(
            'nombref'   => $item1,
            'apellidof' => $item2,
            'dni_becario' => $_POST['dni'],
          );
          $this->Usuario_model->insertarGrupoFamiliar($datafamiliar);
        }
      }
```

y asi por cada INPUT.

Answer (score 0):

La razón por la que no cambia es porque no estás añadiendo el formulario nuevo a tu nuevo tab y lo tienes por fuera lo cual hace que se muestre el mismo contenido en todos, lo que hice fue crear el formulario nuevamente y meterlo en el nuevo div `<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab${tabID}">` con esto cada formulario seré diferente por tab

```js
var button='<button class="close" type="button" title="Remove this page">×</button>';
var tabID = 1;
function resetTab(){
    var tabs=$("#tab-list li:not(:first)");
    var len=1
    $(tabs).each(function(k,v){
        len++;
        $(this).find('a').html('Tab ' + len + button);
    })
    tabID--;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn-add-tab').click(function() {
        tabID++;
        $('#tab-list').append($('<li><a href="#tab' + tabID + '" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab ' + tabID + '<button class="close" type="button" title="Remove this page">×</button></a></li>'));
        $('#tab-content').append($(
            `<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab${tabID}">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nombref">Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombref[]" placeholder="Nombre">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="apellidof">Apellido</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="apellidof[]" placeholder="Apellido">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="vinculo">Vinculo</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="vinculo[]" placeholder="Vinculo">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="celular">Celular</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="celular[]" placeholder="Celular">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="tel/cel">Tel/Cel</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="telcel[]" placeholder="Tel/Cel">
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>`));


    });
    $('#tab-list').on('click', '.close', function() {
        var tabID = $(this).parents('a').attr('href');
        $(this).parents('li').remove();
        $(tabID).remove();

        //display first tab
        var tabFirst = $('#tab-list a:first');
        resetTab();
        tabFirst.tab('show');
    });

    var list = document.getElementById("tab-list");
});
```

```css
#tab-list .close {
        margin-left: 7px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>
                <button id="btn-add-tab" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Add Tab</button>
            </p>
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul id="tab-list" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div id="tab-content" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nombref">Nombre</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombref[]" placeholder="Nombre">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="apellidof">Apellido</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="apellidof[]" placeholder="Apellido">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="vinculo">Vinculo</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="vinculo[]" placeholder="Vinculo">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="celular">Celular</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="celular[]" placeholder="Celular">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="tel/cel">Tel/Cel</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="telcel[]" placeholder="Tel/Cel">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```